# Firebase update data not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I wanted to update the firebase data, but when I update it insert to a new data instead of updating the specific data that I set which is the lastname equal to 'hoo'

```
fb.orderByChild("Lastname").equalTo('hoo').once("value", function(snapshot){
  console.log(snapshot.ref());
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  // var snapref = snapshot.ref();
  snapshot.ref().update({
    FirstName: 'yoyo1'  
  });
})
```

Edit:

```
fb.orderByChild("Lastname").equalTo('hoo').once("child_added", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.ref());
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    // var snapref = snapshot.ref();
    snapshot.ref().update({
      FirstName: 'yoyo1'      
    });  
  })
```

[image]

See the bottom code the new edit code that works by using **'child_added'** not using **value**

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

This means that when you call `snapshot.ref()`, you get the reference to the location that you queried (`fb`) **not** to the child that you selected.

The solution is to loop over the results:

```
fb.orderByChild("Lastname").equalTo('hoo').once("child_added", function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        child.ref().update({
            FirstName: 'yoyo1'      
        });  
    }
})
```

By the way, I'm pretty sure I gave the exact same answer in the past few days. So I highly recommend lurking on the [firebase-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database) tag and learning while you read what others struggle with.

Comment: This code doesn't run. First, there's a close parentheses missing on the second to last line. More importantly, I get an error message: "child.ref is not a function". I don't see how "child" is a Firebase reference.

Comment: Depending on your Firebase SDK version that might need to be `firebase.ref` (without parenthesis). I answered for 2.x (which OP seems to be using), you may be using 3.x where `DataSnapshot.ref` is a property instead of a function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.