# Firebase update() not a function with a query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a property in a record in Firebase Database, with AngularJS. I can set up a query to find my record:

```
  firebase.database().ref('en/').orderByChild('word').equalTo('the').once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      console.log(childSnapshot.val())
    });
  })
```

I can update my property, if I hardcode in the record's key:

```
firebase.database().ref('en/-KloeQHDC-mugPjJMAG4').update({ wordFrequency: 111 })
```

But if I set up a query to find the record and then update it, I get an error message `update is not a function`:

```
firebase.database().ref('en/').orderByChild('word').equalTo('the').update({ wordFrequency: 9001 })
```

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391928/firebase-update-data-not-working) suggests calling `update()` from inside a `forEach` loop:

```
  firebase.database().ref('en/').orderByChild('word').equalTo('the').once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      console.log(childSnapshot.val()); // this works
      childSnapshot.ref().update({ wordFrequency: 9001 });
    });
  });
```

That returns an error message `TypeError: childSnapshot.ref is not a function`. I don't see how `childSnapshot` is a Firebase ref.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781186/firebase-update-specific-fields) says

> When you call update() on a location, Firebase loops over the data
>   that you pass in (in your case asJson) and for each key performs a
>   ref.child(key).set(value).

If `update()` loops over the data, why should I call `update()` from inside a `forEach` loop? The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) doesn't show calling `update()` from inside a `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Database SDK provides a `Reference.update()` method to update data in a single location in a database. Key here is that a `Reference` is a single location in the database, so it is clear what to update.

My pseudo-code explanation about how multi-path updates work applies to how the database server implements it: given a single location/`DatabaseReference` it updates each path in the `update()` call based on that.

A `Query` can match multiple locations in the database, so it doesn't have an `update()` method (or `set()` or `remove()` for that matter).

To update each location matched by a query, you execute the query and then call `update()` on each result - either by a `child_added` listener, or with a `value` listener and a loop like in your last snippet.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) could be clearer. It could explain that update() is easy to use if you have the key, and difficult to use without the key. The example using "ada" as the key is confusing because "ada" doesn't look like a Firebase key (e.g., -kh4j5hf7g67h). I posted an answer to my question that makes update() easy to use, if you keep track of the key. Also, it could have an example with the onComplete function.

Answer (score 1):

After I posted this question I walked the dog, ate dinner, and then the solution came to me. My new rule is, "The key to Firebase queries is to keep track of the key."

This template is for users to update records in the database. They enter a search term in a form field and click the "Search" button. The `$scope.search` handler queries the Firebase database and then populates the form fields with the record's properties:

```
  $scope.search = function() {
    myFirebase_ref.orderByChild('word').equalTo($scope.word).once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      $scope.wordKey = childSnapshot.key;
      $scope.audioArray = childSnapshot.val().audio;
      $scope.ipaArray = childSnapshot.val().ipa;
      $scope.language = childSnapshot.val().language;
      $scope.longLanguage = childSnapshot.val().longLanguage;
      $scope.phonemeArray = childSnapshot.val().phonemes;
      $scope.translationArray = childSnapshot.val().translations;
      $scope.word = childSnapshot.val().word;
      $scope.wordFrequency = childSnapshot.val().wordFrequency;
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Authentication failed:", error.message);
  });
};
```

Note at the top of the property assignments I have `$scope.wordKey = childSnapshot.key;`. I'm keeping track of the record's key.

The user then updates a field. Each field has a button next to it for "Update". Each button goes to a handler. For example, to update the `wordFrequency` field I have this handler:

```
$scope.updateFrequencyRank = function() {
  firebase.database().ref('en/' + $scope.wordKey).update({ wordFrequency: $scope.wordFrequency })
};
```

One line of code and it works! Even better, I made an `onComplete` function to tell me if the update succeeded:

```
$scope.updateFrequencyRank = function() {

  var onComplete = function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Update failed');
    } else {
      console.log('Update succeeded');
    }
  };

  firebase.database().ref('en/' + $scope.wordKey).update({ wordFrequency: $scope.wordFrequency }, onComplete);
};
```